# JAXB : NullPointerException thrown while creating Unmarshaller in JAXB

Tags: jaxb

I have created a Structure for my XML to work with JAXB Unmarshalling 
The problem is taht , the Unmarshaller is not being getting created .

```
JAXBContext jc =  JAXBContext.newInstance("A Fully qualified class name");
Unmarshaller um =  jc.createUnmarshaller();

java.lang.NullPointerException is being thrown at 
Unmarshaller um =  jc.createUnmarshaller();
```

There is nothing on to the statcktrace except java.lang.NullPointerException , so cant able to debug it also .
Could anybody please tell me how to solve this during creating a Unmarshaller ?? for JAXB 2.0

For refernece this is my Parser class

```
public class BADFMMessageParser  {
private static JAXBContext jc = null;
    static {
        try {
        jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("My Fully Qualified class name");
        } catch (Exception x) {
        }
    }
    public static MyClass parse(String str) throws Exception {
        Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        BADFM  badfmMessage = (BADFM) um.unmarshal(new StringReader(requestStr));
        JAXBElement<? extends MyClass> value = badfmMessage.getMessage();
        return value.getValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are seeing a NPE, but you appear to be creating your `JAXBContext` incorrectly.  You could do the following assuming you had a `jaxb.index` file or `ObjectFactory` class in the specified package:

```
JAXBContext jc =  JAXBContext.newInstance("your.domain.model.package");
```

Otherwise you could create your `JAXBContext` directly on the class or classes:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class,Bar.class);
```

**`jaxb.index` File Example**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

**Bootstrap `JAXBContext` on Generated Model Example**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

**Bootstap `JAXBContext` from Classes Example**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: Thanks , i specified the exact qualified packaged name , i verified this by debugging , could you please let me know what is this jaxb.index ?? As the ObjectFactory is automaticaly created by JAXB .

Comment: @yyyi777 - I have added a few examples to my answer.  The part that threw me is in your post you had `"A Fully qualified class name"` and I wanted to make sure you meant `"A Fully qualified package name"`.

Comment: Ya , i tried with all the options ( All trail and errors ) including the package name , but i am still getting this NPE .

Comment: Could you post the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: There is nothing stacktrace except this 3 lines on to the console java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.bacs.tata.util.BADFMMessageParser.parse(BADFMMessageParser.java:26)
 at com.bacs.tata.service.MyAdapter.main(MyAdapter.java:493)

Comment: Which line is 493 in MyAdapter?

Comment: message = BADFMMessageParser.parse(xmlstring);

Comment: Thanks for the concern  the issues are related to Objects they ahve coded  mentioned , currently it is appearing as 74 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Property Order appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists.

Comment: @yyyi777 not sure if that would help btw you may also want to check for what JDK your using because JAXB in JDK 1.6 does sometimes causes issues. JDK 1.6 endorses JAXB 2.0 binding API and thus if you intend to use JAXB 2.1 or higher API then you will have to use 'Java endorsed directory mechanism' to get a workaround. Under this you will have to create a 'endorsed' folder under JRE_HOME/lib directory and put jaxb-api-2.x.jar into JRE_HOME/lib/endorsed directory. For more details see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/

Comment: @yyyi777 in your parse(String str) method, try if this helps:
`BADFM  badfmMessage = ((JAXBElement<BADFM>) um.unmarshal(new StringReader(requestStr))).getValue();
`